# Telegraf is not publishing to cloudwatch via tail/grok plugin

Tags: amazon-cloudwatch, telegraf

I am trying to publish data from a log file to cloudwatch.
I used Telegraf client with Tail plugin, i am using grok_custom_patterns to harvest data.
If i provide a file as output plugin, the data is publishing ok, but if i change this is cloudwatch it is not publishing any data. But other input plugins like cpu usage is publishing data to cloudwatch with out any problem.

Telegraf config:

```
[[outputs.cloudwatch]]
  region = "eu-west-1"
  namespace = "xyz/data"
[[inputs.tail]]
files = ["/home/logs/log-input-file.in"]
from_beginning = false
pipe = false
watch_method = "inotify"
grok_patterns = ["%{CUSTOM_LOG}"]
grok_custom_patterns = '''
CUSTOM_LOG %{GREEDYDATA}"abc_timestamp":"%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:date}"%{GREEDYDATA}"method":"%{WORD:verb}"%{GREEDYDATA}"status_code":%{INT:statusCode}%{GREEDYDATA}"elapsed_time":%{INT:elapsedTime}%{GREEDYDATA}
'''
data_format = "grok"
```

Tried declaring some of the variables as tags, but that made no difference aswell.

Answer (score 0):

Got this working by chaing the pattern,

```
CUSTOM_LOG %{GREEDYDATA}"abc_timestamp":"%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:clientdate:tag}"%{GREEDYDATA}"method":"%{WORD:httpverb:string}"%{GREEDYDATA}"status_code":%{NUMBER:statusCode:int}%{GREEDYDATA}"elapsed_time":%{NUMBER:elapsedTime:int}%{GREEDYDATA}
```